# How to export resource property from the AWS Cloudformation stack?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Below is the cloudformation stack resource.

```
GeneratorAsset:
    Type: "AWS::IoTSiteWise::Asset"
    DependsOn: GeneratorAssetModel
    Properties:
        AssetName: "Generator-1"
        AssetProperties: 
          - 
            LogicalId: !Ref GeneratorAssetModelAttributeLogicalId
            NotificationState: "DISABLED"
          - 
            Alias: "/DayOneEnergyCorp/1/Generator/Power"
            LogicalId: !Ref GeneratorAssetModelMeasurementWatts1mLogicalId
            NotificationState: "DISABLED"
          - 
            Alias: "/DayOneEnergyCorp/1/Generator/Temperature"
            LogicalId: !Ref GeneratorAssetModelMeasurementTempratureLogicalId
            NotificationState: "DISABLED"
          - 
            Alias: "/DayOneEnergyCorp/1/Generator/rpm"
            LogicalId: !Ref GeneratorAssetModelMeasurementRPMLogicalId
            NotificationState: "DISABLED"
          - 
            LogicalId: !Ref GeneratorAssetModelMetricSumWatts5mLogicalId
            NotificationState: "DISABLED"
          - 
            LogicalId: !Ref GeneratorAssetModelMetricRatioAvgRPMRower5mLogicalId
            NotificationState: "DISABLED"
```

> We want to export the below resource's properties from the above resource.

```
        Alias: "/DayOneEnergyCorp/1/Generator/Power"
        LogicalId: !Ref GeneratorAssetModelMeasurementWatts1mLogicalId
        NotificationState: "DISABLED"
```

> How to adjust below output section to achieve this requirement?

```
Outputs:
    SitewiseAsset1:
        Value:
            Ref: GeneratorAsset
        Export:
            Name:
                'Fn::Sub': '${AWS::StackName}-Asset'
```

**Current Output is**

[image]

**Expected output is**

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the current Output? You haven't explain what is your actual issue.

Comment: Hey Marcin, current output only exports the logical id of the asset resource. But we would like to export the sub-properties(as mentioned) defined under that resource.

Comment: Sorry, its not clear. Can you provide example of the current output, and what would be the expected output?

Comment: Hi Marcin, pls check the updated question as per your request. Please let me know if you need more info?